# How do I store encryption secret keys with php?

Tags: php, encryption, filesystems, aes

I have created an app that stores user data in encrypted form using AES-256- CBC. I have done some research and found that it's not a good idea to store the keys in the database or the page itself in code.

So I am looking for an alternative for doing that using PHP to read a file or something.

How do I keep the key safety in the file system and ensure that no one except my PHP application can read this file even if they know the location?

Comment: Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476403/how-to-store-the-encryption-key-safely

Comment: This simple question distills into a question "how to do key management". Quite a broad subject, really. How to protect your key depends on your threat and use model, there is no single good answer.